# Why does blockinfile with state=absent not work for these lines?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a file with the following block of text in it. I have text before and after the text block

```
other_user:
  hash: JKJ;LKJA;LDKJF;LKJA;LKJIUR;JFKLJDQPIRQKJ;LKFJPOQJ 
  #password is: some_pw0
logstash:
  hash: $fj;kdjjfajf;ajKFJ;dfj;dkfja;dfjFJ:LFJj;kj;lfkajs 
  #password is: some_pw
other_user1:
  hash: JJKLJDRKJOPIQMVOIUROIJFAUROJJFIUQWKERJJFKQURJAKDJ 
  #password is: some_pw1
```

I'm trying to remove the block for the logstash user using this code, but it does NOT remove it.

```
- name: Delete existing logstash user
  blockinfile:
    dest: /path_to_file/foo.yml
    state: absent
    block: |
      logstash:
        hash: $fj;kdjjfajf;ajKFJ;dfj;dkfja;dfjFJ:LFJj;kj;lfkajs
        #password is: some_pw
```

I expect the result to be:

```
other_user:
  hash: JKJ;LKJA;LDKJF;LKJA;LKJIUR;JFKLJDQPIRQKJ;LKFJPOQJ 
  #password is: some_pw0
other_user1:
  hash: JJKLJDRKJOPIQMVOIUROIJFAUROJJFIUQWKERJJFKQURJAKDJ 
  #password is: some_pw1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a thing about `blockinfile`. Pay close attention at the [description](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html):

> This module will insert/update/remove a block of multi-line text **surrounded by customizable marker lines**.

The default value for markers: `# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK` where mark is `BEGIN`/`END`.
So if there are no markers in the file, module will treat it as no block found.

Comment: thanks! I missed that part of the description. I used lineinfile instead now, and it works.